# Сортировка двух объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты

У меня есть 2 массива объектов, у каждого объекта есть разные значения и id
Мне нужно их отфильтровать так чтобы сравнивались только id и на выходе я получил 2 массива объектов

примерно так:

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1, x: 31, y: 45}, {id: 2, x: 20, y: 20}, {id: 2, x: 126, y: 520}}]
const arr2 = [{id: 2, x: 58, y: 100}, {id: 2, x: 20, y: 20}, {id: 3, x: 150, y: 520}}]

// *************
// Тут что-то сделать
const arr3 = []
//    ^^^^   Этот массив должен содержать это:
//[
//  { // Первое значение осталось прежним так как id 1 уже есть
//    id: 1,
//    x: 31,
//    y: 45
//  },
//  { // Второе значение прежнее
//    id: 2,
//    x: 20,
//    y: 20
//  },
//  { // Новое значение с id 3
//    id: 3,
//    x: 150,
//    y: 520
//  }
//];
```

PS кому интересно:
Это который принимает пули в моей игре на двоих, их нужно показать первому и второму игроку так чтобы каждый смог видеть чужие пули и свои

Comment: Извиняюсь я должен получить 1 массив объектов* совмещенный с двумя

Comment: Почему игнорируются другие объекты с id:2? Потому что есть совпадение в arr1 и arr2, или по другой причине?

Comment: Забей, я не знаю как изменить вопрос, крч я решил уже, а задание, которое я дал, неправильно описано)